# How to compare a list of a dict to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, compare

Looking to compare a dictionary to a set list, with a given key to use by user. Having a hard time comparing to a list.

**For example:**

I'm given the key:A I would like to compare all test in the dict to the list.

**Expected results:**

For A:

Test1: Okay

Test2: Okay

Test3: Okay

Test4: Invalid

Test5: Okay

**List:**

```
 data = {'A': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
                {'abc', 'def', 'Test2'},
                {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
                {'Test4', 'abc, xyz'},
                {'abc', 'def','Test5'}],
     'B': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
                {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
                {'ghi','Test4'},
                {'Test5', 'efg'}]}
```

**Dictionary:**
Given either the value either A or B as key with the dict below and comparing to the list.

```
testCase =    {'Test1': 'abc',
     'Test2': 'def',
     'Test3': 'ghi',
     'Test4': 'ghi',
     'Test5': 'def'}
```

**Attempt:**

```
given = 'A'

data = {'A': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
                {'abc', 'def', 'Test2'},
                {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
                {'Test4', 'abc, xyz'},
                {'abc', 'def','Test5'}],
     'B': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
                {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
                {'ghi','Test4'},
                {'Test5', 'efg'}]}

testCase =    {'Test1': 'abc',
                'Test2': 'def',
                'Test3': 'ghi',
                'Test4': 'ghi',
                'Test5': 'def'}

for items in data:
    for given in data.keys():
        if testCase in data:
            print (testCase.keys() + ": Okay")
        else:
            print (testCase.keys() + ": Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Idea for solution

- Separate the logic: Put checking one `key` (A or B) + list -pair into one function, (e.g. `check_items()`). Also, checking if `value` (e.g. `'def'`) and the `testname` (e.g. `'Test2'`) are found in the list in the `data[key]` could be separated to another function, `check_test_ok()`

#### Code

Maybe something like

```py
def check_test_ok(testname, value, case_items):
    found = False
    for item in case_items:
        if (testname in item) and (value in item):
            found = True
    if found:
        print(testname, ": Okay")
        return
    print(testname, ": Invalid")


def check_items(case_items, test_case):
    for testname, value in test_case.items():
        check_test_ok(testname, value, case_items)


for key, case_items in data.items():
    print('Checking items for ', key)
    print('=' * 25)
    check_items(case_items, testCase)
    print('\n')
```

#### Example Output:

```
Checking items for  A
=========================
Test1 : Okay
Test2 : Okay
Test3 : Okay
Test4 : Invalid
Test5 : Okay


Checking items for  B
=========================
Test1 : Okay
Test2 : Invalid
Test3 : Okay
Test4 : Okay
Test5 : Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that.

```
 given = 'A'

data = {'A': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
              {'abc', 'def', 'Test2'},
              {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
              {'Test4', 'abc, xyz'},
              {'abc', 'def', 'Test5'}],
        'B': [{'Test1', 'abc'},
              {'abc', 'ghi', 'Test3'},
              {'ghi', 'Test4'},
              {'Test5', 'efg'}]}

testCase = {'Test1': 'abc',
            'Test2': 'def',
            'Test3': 'ghi',
            'Test4': 'ghi',
            'Test5': 'def'}

for items in data.values():

    for given,tests in zip(items,testCase.values()):
        print(given,' : ',tests)
        if tests in given:
            print(testCase.keys() , ": Okay")
        else:
            print(testCase.keys() , ": Invalid")
```